# Hibernate slow first execution of session factory

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, sessionfactory

I've noticed that when I call for the first time a method of sessionFactory of Hibernate, this takes too long to execute, but then runs normally.
I read that this is because here are set all configurations parameters and metadata.

Reading a little bit, I've asumed that this can be optimez by stting hiberante properties in the server.xml of Tomcat.
That's true?
In this case, this is my hiberante.cfg

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pfc?useSSL=false" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.lsikh.unlmaps.model" />
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="max_fetch_depth">3</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Which of those properties could goes to server.xml and how?

Comment: Sounds like a JIT problem. The first time you call the method, Java notices the class is not compiled, and runs it in interpreter mode, which is much slower. Not specifically related to Hibernate, but a big library like that makes it more noticeable. What Java version are you running on?

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8

Comment: Try running it with `JAVA_OPTS=-Xint` as an environment variable. If it becomes just as slow the entire time, then the case is indeed as I predicted, and there isn't much that you can do, other than find a way to force initialization on startup before there is any user access.